# gst-browser fails to start

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I have just installed `gst-browser` (VisualGST) through the Canonical Ubuntu repositories, so I tried to start VisualGST by running `gst-browser` on the command line. However, I am immediately greeted with an error:

```
a Smalltalk Stream:2: Abandon
a Smalltalk Stream:2: Error occurred while not in byte code interpreter!!
/usr/lib/libgst.so.7(+0x74c97)[0x7fb5fa5d1c97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7fb5fa1aaf20]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7fb5fa1aae97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7fb5fa1ac801]
/usr/lib/libgst.so.7(+0x2c6a6)[0x7fb5fa5896a6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigsegv.so.2(+0xe3c)[0x7fb5f9f68e3c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7fb5fa1aaf20]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_check_is_value_type+0x23)[0x7fb5d4e374f3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x20785e)[0x7fb5d551185e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_list_store_new+0xa4)[0x7fb5d5436d94]
[1]    14556 abort (core dumped)  gst-browser
```

What is the cause and meaning of the error, and how can I start VisualGST properly?

GNU Smalltalk version: 3.2.5

EDIT:

This appears to be a known issue. There's a bug report from 2012 on Launchpad: [Smalltalk browser does not launch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnu-smalltalk/+bug/995016).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to to be "known" issue.  As I previously guessed the issue was in libraries link(age).

You can solve your issue either by installing - `libgtk2.0-dev`.

You can find the whole conversation [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/help-smalltalk@gnu.org/msg07868.html).  Here is an excerpt:

> Digging a bit further, I found that the module "gst-gtk-3.2.92.so" is
>   linked against "libgtk-x11-2.0.so", which is (now?) only provided by
>   package: gtk2-devel.

Your second option is to compile it from source.  On Fedora 27 (again from the discussion and link above):

```
I'm on Fedora 27 and after a fresh install this gave me a working build:
sudo dnf install gcc git automake bison flex libtool libtool-ltdl-devel libffi-devel libsigsegv-devel cairo-devel gtk2-devel texinfo

git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/smalltalk.git

cd smalltalk

autoreconf -vi ./configure make

sudo make install
-----------------------
```

For future referece you can find testing gst-browser [gist](https://gist.github.com/bill-auger/7658fff47b7ba5ac65dfc3e5e74b1e6a).

Comment: I know about the mailing list discussion and the GitHub gist. I already have `libgtk2.0-dev` installed as it is an indirect dependency of `gnu-smalltalk-browser`. I am on Debian/Ubuntu. I very much prefer installing from the repositories rather than from source. I guess I'll just have to make do without gst-browser.

Comment: @Flux ah, if you knew about it why didn't you mention it in your question?  I understand it is much easier to get ti from repositories, than building it, but apparently there is no working build from repositories, if you have the `dev` package installed.

Comment: I had the same problem here, trying to install it on Kubuntu 20.04. It still didn't work, even installing libgtk2.0-dev from the repository.

Comment: @kleite probably newer version needed.  You need to investigate it or ask separate question based on you version issues.